# Cycles Particle objects wont raise off the plane in static rtender

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I've scoured the internet for a potential fix to my particle problem but came up mostly empty. I'd like to create a static image with these crystal-like droplets I've made but I can't seem to get them to "lift" off where the emitter plane was positioned. I've made an image before where I had a similar issue in the past but even copying the settings I'd configured for that emitter the droplets wont seem to float upwards on frame 0.
[image]

In my other project I was able to give rise to my particles through the "velocity" XYZ settings but this doesn't seem to work in my new project as it just rotates the object around onto it's sides.
[image]

[BLENDER FILE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/trcyd8s2oormnxs/rain.blend?dl=0)

Comment: You have to change the droplet object center. That you can do very easily in edit mode by moving the droplet mesh and make sure that the object center should be at the surface of the droplet object.